# Not able to load static files in DJANGO app using AWS EC2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

I successfully deployed the Django App on AWS EC2 using gunicorn and NGINX server. But the static files even after configuring the *django.conf* file in */etc/nginx/sites-available/* are not getting loaded into the templates.

django.conf file:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name my_server_name;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/learning-aws/app.sock;
        }

        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/ubuntu/learning-aws/myprofile/core/static/;
        }
}
```

gunicorn.conf file :

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/ubuntu/learning-aws/myprofile
command=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/learning-aws/app.sock myprofile.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log

[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static/')
```

Template Tags used(eg. *base.html*):

```
{% static 'plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}
```

Comment: Have you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: Its not working in the command line:
`No Django settings specified.
Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
Type 'django-admin help' for usage.`

Comment: @NamanMonga it is `$ py manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: `130 static files copied to '/home/ubuntu/learning-aws/core/static', 88 unmodified.`
After reloading supervisor and nginx, issue NOT resolved

Comment: There's `myprofile` in your nginx config but the path reported by `collectstatic` does not contain that directory. Your STATIC_ROOT or your nginx config is incorrect

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, the issue was with my config file only, changed the address and it was running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple mistake, the address of static files was wrong:

```
    # changed
    # alias /home/ubuntu/learning-aws/myprofile/core/static/;
    # to
    alias /home/ubuntu/learning-aws/core/static/;
```

And changed the order of locations of root ('/') and static ('/static') because of the priority of the system.
to:

```
    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name my_server_name;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/learning-aws/app.sock;
        }

        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/ubuntu/learning-aws/myprofile/core/static/;
        }
    }
```